# Android - Analog of Telerik Rotator

Tags: android, page-layout

I'm not sure if such kind if questions have already been answered.. tried to search without success. (will delete if answered, maybe in other words)

I'm a C# developer, and as UI extension use Telerik Package.
There is the control in Telerik called Rotator.
It works just like the page - shows the loop of pages (page by page) in both left and right directions, using touch screen movements.. (LEFT, RIGHT)...

With animation effect transformation from page A to page B.

Example : http://itbrigada.ru/onlinetest/beginscreen.aspx

These pages could contain Layout panels, which I can populate with other controls and group of controls.. like TabHost with ActivityGroup, but +

- Touch screen control of next page
- Animation transformation during page changing

Please, help and refer me to the same UI solution under Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The soltion is **ViewAnimator** + TouchScreen Listener..